# 連鎖決済にてPENDDINGになっている支払の返金

Tags: paypal

連鎖決済にてPENDDINGになっている支払に対して返金処理(Refund API) もしくは決済の取消の処理を行うことができるか？
可能な場合、通常の返金処理と同様にRefund API を実行すればよい認識で問題ないか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refund API を使用して全額返金は可能ですが一部返金はできないと思いますよ。

Comment: PENDINGの支払に対してRefund APIにて全額返金を行った際、
Refund APIの結果には
>[refundStatus] => REFUNDED
が返却されますが
その後、PaymentDetails API にて状態を取得すると
>[transactionStatus] => DENIED
となっており、受取人が''受取拒否を行った''となっています。

実際に受取人が受取拒否を行ったものと、
PENDINGに対して返金処理を行った結果DENIEDになったものを判別する方法がありますか？

Comment: Pendingの支払いに対するRefund APIの実行結果として返ってくるステータスは、
受取人による受け取り拒否と同様”Denied"となるため、APIの返り値で判別する方法はありません。

そこで、判別する方法としてIPNの送信の有無を活用するのはどうでしょう。
Refund APIで返金処理をする場合には、APIの呼び出し元に、transaction[0].status=Deniedという内容のIPNが送信されます。
それに対して、受取人が受取拒否を行った場合には、上記のIPNを送信しません。
IPNの送信の有無を記録することで、返金の違いを判別することができると思いますよ。

Comment: さっそく試してみます！
詳しくお返事いただきありがとうございます！